# Execute command on all PIDs outputted by primary command?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to be able to kill all tasks with a given name by passing their corresponding PID to `kill -9`. I get a list of relevant tasks by running `sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*`, which returns the following:

```
                     USER PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/nvidia0:        root       1756 F...m Xorg
                     gdm        1940 F.... gnome-shell
                     root      12907 F...m Xorg
                     pedro     69644 F.... atom
                     pedro     89407 F.... chrome
                     pedro     89409 F.... chrome
                     pedro     90137 F.... gnome-shell
/dev/nvidia1:        root       1756 F...m Xorg
                     gdm        1940 F...m gnome-shell
                     root      12907 F...m Xorg
                     pedro     59275 F...m python3.6
                     pedro     59278 F...m python3.6
                     pedro     69644 F...m atom
                     pedro     89407 F...m chrome
                     pedro     89409 F...m chrome
                     pedro     90137 F...m gnome-shell
/dev/nvidiactl:      root       1756 F...m Xorg
                     gdm        1940 F...m gnome-shell
                     root      12907 F...m Xorg
                     pedro     59275 F...m python3.6
                     pedro     59278 F...m python3.6
                     pedro     69644 F...m atom
                     pedro     89407 F...m chrome
                     pedro     89409 F...m chrome
                     pedro     90137 F...m gnome-shell
/dev/nvidia-modeset: root       1756 F.... Xorg
                     gdm        1940 F.... gnome-shell
                     root      12907 F.... Xorg
                     pedro     69644 F.... atom
                     pedro     89407 F.... chrome
                     pedro     89409 F.... chrome
                     pedro     90137 F.... gnome-shell
/dev/nvidia-uvm:     pedro     59275 F...m python3.6
                     pedro     59278 F...m python3.6
```

So far I've been painstakingly manually killing individual PIDs corresponding to python3.6 tasks, but this is not very practical! Is there a way to systematically loop through all tasks returned by the `fuser` command and pass the PIDs corresponding to (in this case) python3.6 to a `kill` command using a bash script for example? Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `fuser` output, you could get the pids and `kill` them like this:

```
fuser -v /dev/nvidia* | awk '/python3.6/{print $(NF-2)}' | xargs kill -9
```

If you have duplicates, like in the example, add a `| sort -u`  before last command. Test without last command if you get the pids you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a combination of `pgrep` and `pkill`: using `pgrep` you can find all PIDs, obeying some pattern. Once you have the list of PIDs correct, you can use `pkill` for sending the right signal to those processes.

Comment: OP should identify some new pattern (if exists) for `pgrep` to match python3.6 processes using a certain file. If not, he has to use `fuser` or `lsof` to include file (/dev/nvidia*)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate questions -- another answer can be found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602204/kill-processes-shown-by-sudo-fuser-filtered-by-command-column

You can kill the pids by passing a `-k` to `fuser`.

`$ sudo fuser -k -9 /dev/nvidia*`

Comment: OP wants to filter processes by command name ("python3.6"), additionally to the file using. Also I had a look in man page but didn't find fuser could do this alone.

Answer (score 0):

There's a post over on the Unix Stack Exchange that answers this exact question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602204/kill-processes-shown-by-sudo-fuser-filtered-by-command-column